# Unable to acess kotlin js from javascript

Tags: javascript, gradle, kotlin, npm, webpack

I'm facing the issue where I'm not able to call any kotlin js function and getting 'something' is not defined.

I've tried compiling project with gradle but ended up following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@chris.barbour03/kotlin-js-building-deploying-and-depending-on-it-with-npm-and-webpack-2f7aab544c9f) and compiling with npm.
I attached my project [here](https://github.com/Creeperface01/kotlinjs-test)

EDIT: tested with maven and worked. However since maven is deprecated, I would like to use gradle or npm.

html code:

```
<body>
<script src="test.js"></script> //file generated in bin/bundle
<script>
    (function() {
        let a = new test.Test(); //test - module, Test - my class, error occurrs at this line
        a.test(); //test - method in class Test
    })()
</script>
</body>
```

however it always results in

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "shx rm -rf bin && webpack && shx rm -rf bin/build/kotlin-test*",
    "test": "mocha bin/test"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "kotlin": "^1.3.70"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@jetbrains/kotlin-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "kotlin-test": "^1.3.70",
    "mocha": "^7.1.0",
    "shx": "^0.3.2",
    "webpack": "^4.42.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const KotlinWebpackPlugin = require('@jetbrains/kotlin-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: 'test', // This tells webpack where to begin for bundling

    resolve: {
        modules: ['bin/build', 'node_modules'], // Webpack will use this to look for anything that is required
    },

    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/bin/bundle', // This is where the bundle will go
        filename: 'test.js', // The bundle will be called vectron.js
    },

    plugins: [
        //Step one - Create a test build
        new KotlinWebpackPlugin({
            src: __dirname,                                   // Build Everything
            output: 'bin/test',                               // Output to bin/test
            moduleName: 'test',                            // Will create vectron.js
            moduleKind: 'commonjs',                           // Create commonjs modules
            librariesAutoLookup: true,                        // Uses node_modules for libraries
            packagesContents: [require('./package.json')],    // Points to package.json for dependencies
        }),
        // Step two - Create a production build
        new KotlinWebpackPlugin({
            src: __dirname + '/src',                          // Build only what is in src
            output: 'bin/build',                              // Output to bin/build
            moduleName: 'test',                            // Create a file called vectron.js
            moduleKind: 'commonjs',                           // Create commonjs modules
            metaInfo: true,                                   // Include .meta.js files
            sourceMaps: true,                                 // Include Source mappings
            librariesAutoLookup: true,                        // Uses node_modules for libraries
            packagesContents: [require('./package.json')],    // Points to package.json for dependencies
        }),
    ],
};
```

my class:

```
class Test {

    fun test() {
        println("test")
    }
}
```

EDIT: npm compilation of test.js:

```
(function (_, Kotlin) {
  'use strict';
  var println = Kotlin.kotlin.io.println_s8jyv4$;
  var Kind_CLASS = Kotlin.Kind.CLASS;
  function Test() {
  }
  Test.prototype.test = function () {
    println('test');
  };
  Test.$metadata$ = {
    kind: Kind_CLASS,
    simpleName: 'Test',
    interfaces: []
  };
  _.Test = Test;
  Kotlin.defineModule('test', _);
  return _;
}(module.exports, require('kotlin'))); //error: module is not defined

//# sourceMappingURL=test.js.map
```

maven kotlin plugin output of test.js:

```
if (typeof kotlin === 'undefined') {
  throw new Error("Error loading module 'test'. Its dependency 'kotlin' was not found. Please, check whether 'kotlin' is loaded prior to 'test'.");
}var test = function (_, Kotlin) {
  'use strict';
  var println = Kotlin.kotlin.io.println_s8jyv4$;
  var Kind_CLASS = Kotlin.Kind.CLASS;
  function Test() {
  }
  Test.prototype.test = function () {
    println('test');
  };
  Test.$metadata$ = {
    kind: Kind_CLASS,
    simpleName: 'Test',
    interfaces: []
  };
  _.Test = Test;
  Kotlin.defineModule('test', _);
  return _;
}(typeof test === 'undefined' ? {} : test, kotlin);
```

Comment: What is the content of generated `test.js` file?

Comment: Edited the post

Comment: The next logical question would be: what is the content of `test.js` generated with *maven*?

Comment: It's different. The kotlin plugin for maven processes sources differently. Also it is outdated so I cannot refer to it. In kotlin docs they recommend to use gradle  because of this.

Comment: Preliminary guess: play with `moduleKind` in your `webpack.config.js`

Comment: Obviously, it's different. That is why it's content is interesting

Answer (score 0):

moduleKind was wrong in the build.gradle. Setting it to 'plain' fixed the issue.
Thank you